# python mysql database datetime

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

i have a value in a datetime column at my database, and i want to print it like this

```
        cursor.execute("SELECT * from botkeys WHERE mykey = "+r)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        r = None
        while r is None:
            r = open('licensekey.txt', 'r').read()
            for row in rows:   
                if r == row[2]:
                    time.sleep(.5)
                    print('Welcome ' + row[1] + ' Have fun.')
                    print('Type: ' + row[3])
                    print('Expiration Date: ', row[4])
                    break
```

the

```
print('Welcome ' + row[1] + ' Have fun.')
print('Type: ' + row[3])
```

works perfectly because they are text values not datetime values but the

```
print('Expiration Date: ', row[4])
```

isnt working it says

```
Message: 'Expiration Date: '
Arguments: (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0),)
```

And when i use

```
print(row[4])
```

It shows me the datetime value that i put in the database table perfectly.

so how can i print the str + datetime of my database that should give me something like

```
Expiration Date: 01/01/2021
```

Comment: print('Expiration Date: ', datetime.strftime(row[4], '%Y-%m-%d'))

Comment: still same problem

Comment: print('Expiration Date: ' + row[4].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
this worked for me, thanks tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using

```
print('Expiration Date: ' + row[4].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```